# How do I automatically update the html output of a haml file like I do with a sass and css file?

Tags: haml, sass

**"Watching a file"** helps me to automatically update the changes I make in the **sass** file to the **css** output.

To watch a Sass file is very simple:

```
sass --watch input.sass:output.css
```

but for a Haml file I can't find a similar command

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this post: [Possible to "watch" both HAML and SASS at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105544/possible-to-watch-both-haml-and-sass-at-the-same-time)

the answer says that StaticMatic can do it. haven't tried it yet though