# Possible to "watch" both HAML and SASS at the same time?

Tags: haml, sass

I'd like to be able to update/save both my html and css on-the-fly, but I can't figure out how to watch both HAML and SASS at the same time.

Thanks!

Comment: We're going to need more information here: what platform are you working with and what do you mean by "watch"?

Comment: I'm working on Windows through the Command Prompt. And by "watch" I mean, SASS has a command that will wait for .sass (or .scss) files to be modified and saved, and then it will update the .css file with the changes.
HASS doesn't offer anything like this out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can only use StaticMatic or some other third party stuff to watch both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect for you: a free online SASS/SCSS-HAML editor, Voyage, developed by Zhi-Qiang Lei (thanks!). Very useful for beginners to practice, and for everyone to test snippets quickly.

http://voyage-editor.herokuapp.com/

Hope it helps